# How to draw and fill a rectangle in a PyQtGraph plot at position where mouse is clicked

Tags: python, pyqt5, rectangles, pyqtgraph

I am using PyQt5 and PyQtGraph.  I have simplified the example code below.  Then I want to draw in the plot view a small red rectangle each time the mouse is clicked at the position where the mouse is clicked, thus accumulating several red rectangles in the plot view.  The code below has a #??? comment where I need some help with code that will draw the red rectangle(s).

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget, plot

# *********************************************************************************************
# *********************************************************************************************

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle("My MainWindow")
        self.qPlotWidget = pg.PlotWidget(self)
        self.qPlotWidget.setLabel("bottom", "X-Axis")
        self.qPlotWidget.setLabel("left", "Y-Axis")
        self.qPlotWidget.scene().sigMouseClicked.connect(self.mouseClickedEvent)

        data1 = np.zeros((2, 2), float) # create the array to hold the data
        data1[0] = np.array((1.0, 10.0))
        data1[1] = np.array((2.0, 20.0))

        pen1 = pg.mkPen(color=(255,0,0), width=1) # red
        self.qPlotWidget.plot(data1, pen=pen1, name="data1")

    def mouseClickedEvent(self, event):
        print("mouseClickedEvent")
        pos = event.scenePos()
        if (self.qPlotWidget.sceneBoundingRect().contains(pos)):
            mousePoint = self.qPlotWidget.plotItem.vb.mapSceneToView(pos)
            print("mousePoint=", mousePoint)

            # draw and fill a 2-pixel by 2-pixel red rectangle where
            # the mouse was clicked at [mousePoint.x(), mousePoint.y()]
            # ??? add code here

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        size = self.geometry()
        self.qPlotWidget.setGeometry(10, 10, size.width()-20, size.height()-20)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MainWindow()
    screen = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
    w.setGeometry(100, 100, screen.width()-200, screen.height()-200) # x, y, Width, Height
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is to create an empty scatter plot item and add it to `self.qPlotWidget`. Then in `mousrClickedEvent` you could add the mouse position to the list of points of this scatter plot item, i.e.

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        .... as before ....

        # add empty scatter plot item with a red brush and a square as the symbol to plot widget
        brush = pg.mkBrush(color=(255,0,0))
        self.scatterItem = pg.ScatterPlotItem(pen=None, size=10, brush=brush, symbol='s')
        self.qPlotWidget.addItem(self.scatterItem)


    def mouseClickedEvent(self, event):
        pos = event.scenePos()
        if (self.qPlotWidget.sceneBoundingRect().contains(pos)):
            mousePoint = self.qPlotWidget.plotItem.vb.mapSceneToView(pos)

            # add point to scatter item
            self.scatterItem.addPoints([mousePoint.x()], [mousePoint.y()])
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar thing myself, but I needed to be able to size the rectangle myself and extract the coordinates of the rectangle. Eventually I came up with writing a class based on pyqtgraph `PlotWidget`, but with the right mouse click being used for drawing a rectangular ROI (instead of zooming). I've shared it here in case someone who stumbles onto this thread is looking for something similar

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore
from PyQt6.QtGui import QMouseEvent, QKeyEvent
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
import pyqtgraph as pg


class RectROIPlotWidget(pg.PlotWidget):
    """PlotWidget with a rectangular ROI that can be drawn by right-clicking and dragging the mouse"""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Initialize method of the RectROIPlotWidget"""
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        # disable autorange by default to avoid unexpected behaviour when drawing ROI
        self.plotItem.vb.autoRange(False)

        # add rectangular ROI
        self.roi_rect = None
        self.reset_roi_rect()

    def reset_roi_rect(self):
        """Reset the rectangular ROI"""
        # remove ROI from plot if it exists
        if self.roi_rect in self.items():
            self.removeItem(self.roi_rect)

        # define start point
        self.start_point = [0, 0]

        # add rectangular ROI
        self.roi_rect = pg.RectROI(
            pos = [-1, -1],
            size = [0, 0],
            rotatable = False,
            invertible = True,
            pen = pg.mkPen([200, 200, 200], width=2, style=QtCore.Qt.PenStyle.DotLine),
            hoverPen = pg.mkPen([255, 255, 255], width=2, style=QtCore.Qt.PenStyle.DashLine)
        )
        self.addItem(self.roi_rect)
        self.roi_rect.setZValue(1000)

        # set flag for drawing ROI
        self.draw_flag = False

    def mousePressEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent):
        """Mouse press event handling the start of drawing the ROI
        
        Arguments
        ---------
            - event (QMouseEvent): mouse press event
        """
        if event.button().name == 'RightButton':
            self.reset_roi_rect()
            self.draw_flag = True
            mouse_point = self.plotItem.vb.mapSceneToView(event.position())
            self.start_point = [mouse_point.x(), mouse_point.y()]
        else:
            super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent):
        """Mouse move event handling the drawing of the ROI
        
        Arguments
        ---------
            - event (QMouseEvent): mouse move event
        """
        if self.draw_flag:            
            mouse_point = self.plotItem.vb.mapSceneToView(event.position())
            bottom_left = [min(self.start_point[0], mouse_point.x()), min(self.start_point[1], mouse_point.y())]
            top_right = [max(self.start_point[0], mouse_point.x()), max(self.start_point[1], mouse_point.y())]
            self.roi_rect.setPos(bottom_left)
            self.roi_rect.setSize([top_right[0] - bottom_left[0], top_right[1] - bottom_left[1]])

        super().mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent):
        """Mouse release event handling the end of drawing the ROI
        
        Arguments
        ---------
            - event (QMouseEvent): mouse release event
        """
        if event.button().name == 'RightButton':
            self.draw_flag = False

        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event: QKeyEvent):
        """Key press event handling the removal of the ROI when pressing escape
        
        Arguments
        ---------
            - event (QKeyEvent): key press event
        """
        # remove ROI on pressing escape
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key.Key_Escape:
            self.roi_rect.setPos([-1, -1])
            self.roi_rect.setSize([0, 0])

        super().keyPressEvent(event)

    def get_roi_rect_coords(self) -> tuple:
        """Get the coordinates of the rectangular ROI
        
        Returns
        -------
            - tuple: tuple with two lists:
                - list: bottom left coordinates of the ROI
                - list: top right coordinates of the ROI
        """
        # get bottom left and size of ROI
        bottom_left = list(self.roi_rect.pos())
        size = list(self.roi_rect.size())

        # determine top right of ROI
        top_right = [bottom_left[0] + size[0], bottom_left[1] + size[1]]

        return bottom_left, top_right


app = pg.mkQApp("Plotting Example")
win = QMainWindow()
p = RectROIPlotWidget()
win.setCentralWidget(p)
win.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.exec()
```

[image]